# Unable to initialize WebSocket structure in typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, websocket

## Problem

When I run the following code, I receive following error.

index.tsx

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';

export default function Home() {
  const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1919/ws');
  
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  );
}
```

error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object
```

## Conditions for reproducing the errors

- Init Project

  ```
  yarn create next-app
  ```

  All options were selected as defaults.
- add `ws`

  ```
  yarn add ws
  yarn add @types/node @types/ws
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSocket from ws is not designed to work with a browser, so you can't use it. Instead you need to use the browser native WebSocket and assure to be using it in client side with useEffect, like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1919/ws');
  }, [])

  return (
      <div>Home</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ! Why I should init socket in useEffect?

Comment: Beacuse otherwise the code is running sever side, and WebSocket is client side. useEffect with empty array only executes when page is loaded and the code will be executed client side

Comment: Thank you very much. When I ran it on my end, without useEffect, I got the error `ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.` Why is this?

Comment: As I already said, outside useEffect you are runnning server side code and WebSocket only exists on client side. Hope this helps you